# What programming languages are good for novice testers to learn?

Tags: automated-testing, learning, languages

I'm looking for a programming language to recommend to a friend considering teaching herself software testing.  I have a friend who is interested in learning software testing, and I believe strongly that today's testers absolutely have to have automation skills if they don't want to hit a glass ceiling after a few years (or become super-star exploratory testers . . . but not everyone wants the stress of *having* to be a super-star).

I can't look to my own experiences, because I did a 4-year CSE degree that was geared toward developers, and my education isn't light-weight enough.  I want something relatively easy to learn that will give the tester the greatest bang for their buck in developing good, maintainable automation.

I know Ruby is used for a couple of test tools - Watir and Cucumber - and something that works with Selenium, WatiN, or Watir would be good.  The two favorite languages locally for developers seem to be Java and C#, and she will be working locally.  Whatever she learns needs to have good resources for novices at programming to self-teach, whether those be books, online tutorials, or online communities.  Something that isn't too expensive to learn would probably be preferred ('free IDEs are available and there are good free tutorials and information to learn from' is ideal).  Also, something that is harder to write bad code in would be good, since I want her to be able to avoid brittle, unmaintainable tests.  She is highly motivated to learn, so a *very* useful language that will take 6 months of hard work to get a usable level of skill is preferable to a slightly useful language that she could use in a single month.  At the same time, any time she spends learning to program is time she could be spending practicing exploratory testing or learning other great test skills - so ease of learning does matter.

> Also - I do realize that programming is one very small piece of being a good tester.  I just have a better handle on self-teaching the rest of the testing skills, since I self-taught myself those areas and can pass on what worked for me or what I wish I'd known.  I don't want anyone to think I believe you can learn to be a good tester by just learning to program; rather, I just don't have a good handle on the easiest way to start programming as a tester since I started testing as a programmer.

Comment: Python is widely considered best language for beginners, much simpler than Java or C#. Once you understand programming in Python, it will be easier to learn other languages (and you will understand why Python is easier).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I kind of have the opposite experience: I learned some coding first then became a tester. My advice is that **any** programming/coding experience is beneficial for testing. Any way you can better understand what the application is doing in front of you, the better you can test it. Plus, specific tools and languages come and go in use and popularity: learning the fundamentals will age quite well in the long run.

Programming languages comes in all shapes and sizes, but have some main things in common (usually) so seeing more is good. Plus if she's willing to learn, then larger ideas such as Object Oriented Programming, web and command scripting, programming style and code reuse will be helpful overall. Definitely look at scripting languages like Python or Perl: they can be indispensable for daily testing tasks.

As for specific suggestions, Python is a good language to start with. It's easily available and platform independent, which is great in the long run. It also has some mature testing tools (nose, unittest) and a large range of other libraries and tools (BeautifulSoup for HTML processing, Selenium tools). It also has a good community for help, and straightforward syntax. I've also heard good things about Ruby for similar reasons, and maybe the testing tools (Watir in particular) are more mature. I've recently learned a small bit of C#, and it's good as well.

Comment: I agree that any programming language experience would be beneficial.  I also agree that Python might be a good place to start. I have a Python expert on my team, and he is able to use it in a wide variety of test contexts.

Comment: Python entered my head w/ Ruby, and it looks like it works w/ Selenium (both RC and IDE).  I'm definitely biased towards a language that can be used to teach OOP.  I'll have to look into its testing tools.  Thanks, this looks promising.

Comment: "I'm definitely biased towards a language that can be used to teach OOP."  Why?

Comment: Hi Joe, a couple of reasons.  Because understanding OOP makes understanding developer code easier, and that opens up possibilities for white-box testing and enhances debugging abilities.  Because writing maintainable automated tests is often made easier if the tester understands even basic OOP (e.g., Page Objects for UI testing).  And there's probably an unreasoning bias mixed in from my own dev-heavy background :p

Comment: Another vote for Python (+ Selenium bindings) and Shell scripting.

Comment: Python as first choice for few reasons (1) simple syntax optimized for readability by humans (computer has to work harder, but syntax makes programmer more productive); (2) flexible data structures, data literals and comprehension saves lots of lines of code; (3) excellent text processing, so you can use Python to develop little custom tools; (4) beginner can write non-OO code and use existing objects, which is much easier approach; (5) MIT has it as intro language to programming - gives you hint. From 10+ languages I know, Python is the best for beginners (and good for experts too!)

Answer (score 13):

I don't think any specific language is better or worse than any other, although I will say (from experience) that going from Java or any other "pointerless" language to one that does have pointers is not a pleasant experience.

Apart from that - the important parts of automation and coding are recognizing the problem that the code needs to solve, and being able to express the solution in a way that can be handled with a logical series of steps.

Object-oriented and data-driven are nice ways to handle the data that drives the steps, but the core is finding the bits the automation has to interact with, and the logic processing.

My recommendation here would be to pick something that's got a lot of support and wide application, make sure the logical structures are learned (if-else, case statements, the various looping types and so forth), and it won't matter past what's currently most practiced what the language is.

I learned programming this way, and I've never had much difficulty picking up new languages (I first learned Java, then Javascript with HTML, various other scripting languages, VBScript with ASP.NET, and I'm currently working with a script flavor of Delphi)

Comment: Definitely a good tip on languages with/without pointers. Of course, going the other way (C++ to C# for example) is awesome!

Comment: joshin4colours - yes! Starting with Java and then trying to work in C++ was not a pleasant experience. If I had to do that professionally, I'd have to sit down and learn pointers and how they work.

Answer (score 10):

I would recommend a slightly different approach. Rather than initially focusing on a particular language, I would recommend focusing on programming concepts.

Some good books include *Programming Langugae Concepts* by Carlo Ghezzi, or *Prelude to Programming: Concepts and Design* by Elizabeth Drake. (Another great book is *Programming in the Key of C Sharp* by Charles Petzold. It uses C# to teach programming concepts.)

If someone learns the semantics of basic operations, and the basics of data types, control structures, program design, and data structures then learning a particular language is reduced to learning the syntax for that language.

You don't learn to think or rationalize ideas by simply learning how to repeat words in another language.

Comment: Basically I agree, although there's more than just "learning the syntax for that language"

Answer (score 7):

I like Everyday Scripting with Ruby: for Teams, Testers, and You by Brian Marick

It teaches Ruby but also shows how it can be used to help in testing - so instead of reading theory and going through exercises there is the chance to actually put some of the code into use.

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend to start from JavaScript

This language is not too complicated for beginners to start writing some very basic code. From the other hand it is a powerfull language that is used not only for client side but also for server side development. This language has a hidden potential and the popularity of its still growing, see http://langpop.com/

Also person knowing JavaScript can learn Java or C# , but in this case good understanding of OOO concept will be required

As a language it is used in different automation tools, like Selenium and there are a tone of tutorials (just google for 'JavaScript tutorial' and select what you want)

Answer (score 4):

There's a good argument for trying to use whatever language the devs are using, so to that end I'd suggest C#.

I don't think that I really subscribe to the idea that you should start out with a 'gateway' language and work your way up - at the beginning learning programming you can tend to be very hung up on the syntax, rather than concepts, so trying to learn more than one language is a complication.

C# has the free express visual studio IDEs, which are going to be packed with auto-completion and help files. I think there is some decent context for automated testing in C# from some of the microsoft testing blogs also.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend starting with a scripting language. It could be Perl, Python, Ruby. It’s easy to start with this languages and they allows to easily solve many standard problems, like HTML report generation, sending emails, generate test data etc. Those languages could be used with Selenium RC to create the automated Web tests. First of all, a beginner need to understand what he can do with programming language. The dynamic languages shows a lot of advantages for daily work.

Only than I would recommend to start with strongly typed languages, like C# or Java. There are a lot of important details in that languages that makes it hard to understand.

By default, tester must know the Windows Batch Files scripting.

Comment: (note: this comment is from @mohammed-sameeh - it was added as an answer because a new user doesn't have enough points to comment yet. I think it's a good question, I wondered that too!)
"dmitry Zhariy
why Windows Batch Files scripting is important for tester"

Comment: The Windows Batch scripting saves a lot of time. I am installing my application under test using the msiexec, copying the predefined config files automatically after the installation, downloading the recent builds from the overseas servers, backuping and restoring the oracle DB in one click. Why should I do all this routine operations manually? I am automating them with batch files and command line tools. Instead of Batch files you also can use Powershell, JScript etc. but I prefer to automate my tasks using batch.And it saves my working hours each day.

Answer (score 4):

Everything has a context.

- Will you join or start an automation project? Follow the language of this project.
- Do you want a fast learning curve on the basics of programming and automation? Take a look in Python; do a Codeacademy-like course and play with each entry on the Learn X in Y Minutes site - try run and change things to see what happens. After that, learn the Page Object pattern auto-critically, always checking if you are building something extendable, using good OO programming. The Python tutorials and courses lack sometimes this sort of critic.
- Do you want to look at the market? Java is more used than C# by big companies, because they have dev people used to Java - Javascript is closely used, depending on the region you are. The con here is that the community for automation in these language is not so strong.
- Do you want to experiment with dozen of open source tools built-upon Selenium? Take a look at Ruby; the Cucumber environment is extremely active and the integration with Rails is the focus. Javascript's community is as active as Ruby's. These languages have lots of 'magic programming', few lines of code that do bunch of things. I love them for it, but I know these sort of elegant code can be difficult to catch if you are novice and/or learned to strict C-like programming.

Answer (score 3):

The language's utility depends upon the type of automation.  For driving applications from the outside, or for interacting with a command line interface, a scripting language like Bash or PERL is hard to beat.  For interacting with an API, the API's own language is never a bad choice, especially if one has well-documented examples to learn from.  (I personally think Clojure is a better language than Java for testing a Java API, but I am not sure I would recommend this to a beginner.)  For testing web interfaces, JavaScript might the right language, or it might be a "bigger" language environment like Java or C#, assuming there are well-documented examples (or willing teachers) to learn from.

Answer (score 3):

I've mostly used Ruby and Python languages recently in my role as a tester, also would recommend learning command line scripting both on Unix/Linux and Windows machines.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend 3 that iconic of how bugs are created:
C# - this will show a modern object oriented approach, hard to have bugs that are pure typos.
Objective C, managing resources and the unique C syntax, so easy to mess up and wonderful bugs are easily created
JavaScript - this or some variant of will be useful in automated testing tools as well has understanding loosely typed languages.

Overall I think it helpful to have some knowledge of the language you AUT is written in.

Answer (score 2):

Get the OOPS concept first, Start with Java Script, VB Script. Before that it is good to know HTML, CSS styles. Once you are expert on these then go to Ruby Scripts, C#, later on to PERL scripts if you want to learn Security testing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your friend to start one option is the Head First Programming book, it uses Python to teach programming and some design.  I did it a little while ago to sort of strengthen some basics I wanted to have in programming, although considering I had been doing it in a testing capacity on my own for awhile I got a few good things from it.  For someone who has not programmed it looked to me like a good introduction.

Answer (score 1):

I am fairly new in Software Testing and been trying to self study automated testing too. I've been using this free software testing course at Udacity.com. It has notes and forums which are really helpful as well. It uses Python. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I started out as as tester with no programming skills whatsoever.

I started to make use of a tool called "Autoit" for my automation.
it is a slight deviation of VB and the user codes in SCITE. That being said, 100% opensource.

The major benefit is the community/Forum. Whenever a question is asked there, no answers are given unless the user actually pasted a piece of the code that they have struggled with, thus forcing the user to learn. It's also VERY WELL documented so the need to ask questions is kept down to a minimum if you are prepared to do some research first.

If I have not said this before, If you can click on it or use you keyboard, the Autoit can automate it!..

I currently use it to run a series of tests on each deployment we have, If something fails, then the deployment stops and All devs are notified. (we run nightly deployments..)

Ill gladly supply more information and assistance if needed and deem this the best to give access to both worlds, (programming and Testing)

Comment: AutoIT is a good tool. I've used it in the past.  However, I'm pretty sure that AutoIT is freeware, but *not* open source.  See: http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/license.htm

Answer (score 0):

I am a Ruby fan so I can recommend that route.

Rather than Watir and Cucumber I look to directly use Capybara.

https://rubygems.org/gems/capybara

Although commonly used within rails applications, it can be used outside of them too and provides a nice DSL for working with Selenium commands.
For an example see my https://github.com/durrantm/basic_app
Note how it sets:

```
Capybara.run_server = false
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
Capybara.app_host = 'http://www.google.com'
```

---

With the right use of Page Object selectors and helper method you can end up with readable specs such as

```
...
find(p.css_has_license).click
fill_out_driver p
fill_in p.css_driver1_age_licensed, with: age_licensed
select credit_evaluation_option, from: p.css_credit_rating
select education_level_option, from: p.css_driver1_education
...
```

You can probably guess that we're collecting consumer car insurance information on our site!

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who is new to testing, having an understanding of programming language is an advantage. Whether you talk about manual testing or automation testing, the testers should develop the knowledge of programming languages sooner or later in order to test better when it comes to code issues.

Nevertheless, when it comes to any languages that are good to have for novice testers, would be Python and Java. Especially, when the most part of the test automation runs through Java, having access to Java could help testers quickly understand the concepts of automation testing. Besides, Python being a language with simple syntax could be easily learned by testers and could help QAs to have better exposure to testing.