# Selenium with multiple languages gives any additional features

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium2, manual-testing, selenium-webdriver

I am new to Automation Testing.  By googling about Selenium I gained a some  knowledge on Selenium. But I have small doubt i.e., Selenium will support the multiple languages like Javascript with Node.js, Java, Php, .Net, and Python.

Do we get any addition features by using the different technologies/language? Or else it was just flexiblity for a developers to work with Selenium?

Comment: You want to use multiple languages at the same time? Or are you asking what is the best language to develop Selenium tests in? Possible duplicate of http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/7726/should-i-learn-python-or-java-to-get-into-test-automation-i-am-new-to-programmi/

Comment: I think the OP is asking whether one Selenium capabilities vary between language bindings.

Answer (score 2):

So selenium was created in java, so they have all of the advantages of updates and community for questions. I personally like C# because of my background with the .NET technologies. I know that people have recommended that I switch to java because of the community base, and how quickly things are updated for their technology. So to answer your question, none of the languages have a necessarily "additional features" but java is going to be your best bet for most up to date. I hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Selenium IDE to make tests and export to C# you will find that not all commands are availible. So you dont gain any features but you might lose some in the translation process. Essentially, a thrid party plugin converts from Seleniese to whatever language.

Use whatever language you feel comfortable using.

Answer (score 0):

The interesting part of Selenium (the part that controls the browser) -- is a Javascript library that runs in the browser.  The multi-language API is a set of libraries that talk to that Javascript library.  Each API has the same browser control primitives.

There are other libraries that might make working with Selenium more convenient, e.g. support for page objects.  Those are not part of the Selenium project and may not be available in every language that Selenium supports.

Answer (score 0):

Read essay about the evolution of programming languages [language for next 100 years](http://www.paulgraham.com/hundred.html) and another one, finding a [language to beat averages](http://www.paulgraham.com/avg.html) which explores language expressive power, using Blub as example (to avoid religious wars - because selecting a language is for many people emotional issue like selecting a sports club).

Before you start test automation you need to **learn programming. Python is widely considered as best language to learn programming** (helps programmer to handle many tasks which C/C++/C#/Java does not) and has excellent Selenium bindings (and is excellent language for QA tests, because C#/Java are more focused on optimizing computer performance, while Python optimizes **programmer's productivity**.